# Spark DF from CSV file with separator surrounded by quotes character in column value

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I have a CSV file (^ separated) in an S3 bucket. CSV file looks like this:

```
   id^"name"^"address" 
   1^"sam"^"TN" 
   2^"giri"^"Dummy"^"Value"
```

Expected O/P:

```
id | name | address
1  | sam  | TN
2  | giri | Dummy"^"Value
```

But **Dummy"^"Value** - this value is getting split into 2 different cols. I have tried all csv options but nothing is working out. And I have no control over source data.

Code:

```
df = spark.read.option("header",True)\
.option("delimiter",'^') \
.option("quote", "\"")   \
.option("escape", "\"")  \
.csv(<filepath>)
```

Please share if there are any work around. Thanks.